# store the value of session mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a web app in which i am fetching data from database

in my modal I have a public string `public string login { get; set; }` i want to store my login in `string login` and i store my login into a session `HttpContext.Current.Session["loginuser"]` now i want to store the value of session into my `public string` is this possible?

and i tried like this

`public string login { set=HttpContext.Current.Session["loginuser"].tostring();}`

i know this is wrong but i just tried it and as expected it is not working

and i tried like `        public string login { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string word { get; set; }

```
    public bool compdetailsrpt(string login, string name, string type, string word)
    {
        login = HttpContext.Current.Session["loginuser"].ToString();`
```

this also but the value of `login` is showing null

Comment: If the value of `login` is null after you tried to set it with a basic `public string { get; set; }`, this means that you didn't set the `Session["loginuser"]` or that `Session["loginuser"]` is filled with a null value.

Comment: i thought the same but when i prints `Session["loginuser"]` the value is showing on other pages

Comment: Also the place in your code is important. If you try to access HttpContext in the constructor of the `Controller` it will give a null value.

Comment: @DDDSoft sir its my model

Comment: can you show your Model?

Comment: @DDDSoft posted as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124767/discussion-between-ddd-soft-and-ibrahim-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

U can use a private variable to store the value:

```
private string login;
public string Login
{
    get { return login; }
    set { login = value; }
}

public bool compdetailsrpt(string login, string name, string type, string word)
{
    Login = HttpContext.Current.Session["loginuser"].ToString();
    return Login != null;
}
```